# digital feedback stability

Tags: analog, circuit-design, integrated-circuit, feedback, switched-capacitor

Good evening.
i confused to extract the transfer function of the following loop, (shown below)
where Cin is a switch cap operated by feedback Fout and Cx switch cap is operated by an external Fref = const. LPF is say first order filter and VCO with factor K. clock divider is N.

I would wonder to see transfer function any z or s domain with some short explanations.
Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: There are lots of examples of PLL‘s on the web for S domain. The problems are the limits in mixers and amplifiers that become nonlinear as gain then drops to zero or changes polarity in each cycle causing the limits of capture range. Dual BW methods are often used to improve capture then low jitter

Comment: So simple analysis fails in either domain

Comment: I confusing with voltage input and Fout feedback signal. In my analysis:
 (Vtmp-Vref)*Cin/Cf*Fout-Vref*Cx/Cf*Fref*1/s*K/N/s=Fout ....

Comment: Frequency feedback is stable yet has more jitter, phase feedback has less jitter but limited capture range, voltage input is an internal parameter

Comment: In general I do understand the jitter reasons, but I confused to extract the final transfer function. the general feedback theory results in H(s) = A(s)/(1+B*A(s)).  But here, in my case, the input signal is voltage and the output is frequency, that multiply each other.

Answer (score 1):

This is a sample and hold mixer where the output is the difference phase, frequency.

What is not shown is the fout is converted to a very narrow pulse which results in a DC voltage when in sync. The gain is proportional to the input signal so it is linear mixer.

The BW of the system with phase lead compensation for PID parameters determined the capture range of this PLL as well as the signal input and its SNR are details to improve this simple model.